# Identifying IDs whose transactions satisfy a specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been pounding my head against the wall on this one for a while.  I have a set of data where I need to identify the CUSTOMERs whose group of transactions satisfy a specific condition.  I've pasted in a small snip of the dataset below.  We could call the table "A".  I hope the way I'm pasting this in is legible in the question output!

I'm looking for a way to identify only the CUSTOMERs whose group of transactions satisfy the following condition:

- Within the CUSTOMER's group of transactions there must exist at least 1 case where a TRANSTYPE 21 transaction has a DATE *later* than a TRANSTYPE 17 transaction.  (Note that the dates here are the typical Excel "days" from 1/1/1900, although this shouldn't matter for the query.)

Any help on this would be very greatly appreciated!

```
CUSTOMERID, TRANSID, TRANSTYPE, DATE

0027, 2, 17, 40948
0027, 3, 21, 40950
0085, 4, 17, 40955
0187, 14, 17, 41199
0187, 15, 21, 41214
0187, 16, 17, 41244
0513, 1, 17, 40940
0513, 5, 21, 40981
0565, 8, 21, 41032
0565, 11, 17, 41080
0715, 6, 17, 41009
0715, 7, 21, 41009
2780, 9, 17, 41039
2985, 10, 17, 41069
2985, 12, 21, 41091
2985, 13, 17, 41144
```

Comment: Why are you storing a date as an integer? That is what the datetime data type is for.

Comment: Are 17 and 21 the only possible values for TRANSTYPE?

Comment: -abatishchev Yeah, I understand the date type looks odd but I thought it was easier to insert here.

Comment: -ExactaBox  In this case 17 and 21 are the only 2 types but thank you and good observation.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.CUSTOMERID
FROM a
  INNER JOIN a b ON a.CUSTOMERID = b.CUSTOMERID
WHERE a.DATE > b.DATE
  AND a.TRANSTYPE = 21
  AND b.TRANSTYPE = 17
```

Comment: Thank you so much SWeko and Dave!  I'm learning more every day.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select CUSTOMERID, TRANSID, TRANSTYPE, DATE
from A a1
where TRANSTYPE=17
and Exists(select * from a a2 where a2.CUSTOMERID=a1.CUSTOMERID and a2.TRANSID=21 and a2.Date>a1.Date)
```

Comment: Vielen Dank Bummi!  Das half mir sehr!  Fröhliche Weihnachten!

Comment: By the way, I'm American...  I know Schwanzenstueck doesn't really mean anything.  It's an inside joke from a movie.

Comment: Merry Christmas you too, the weather with you seems to fit;-)